# a problem when using ```\usepackage{sectsty}``` and ``` \usepackage{titlesec}```

Tags: titlesec, sectsty, vietnamese

In my project, I use these packages `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\usepackage{titlesec}`.

However, everytime I put a section into a center environment, for instance "The first saying", the ouput I get was extended in term of space between each word "The", "first", "saying", which totally fill the line with its space.

How can I fixed that ? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc, vietnam}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\section*{The first saying}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: IMNSHO, loading both `titlesec` and `secsty` is asking for trouble, as is running `\begin{center} \section*{The first saying} \end{center}`. What exactly do you hope to achieve? Why aren't you running `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\sectionfont{\centering}` in the preamble and ` \section*{The first saying} ` in the body of the document?

Comment: Off-topic: `left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=3cm`. Incidentally, `13pt` is not an option recognized by the `report` document class and is simply ignored. Give `12pt` a shot.

Answer (score 3):

It's my experience that loading both [sectsty](https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) and [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) can lead to unexpected outcomes, to put it politely. AFAICT, there's never a good reason for loading both packages. Choose one or the other, *but not both*.

It's not clear to me which formatting objective you're trying to achieve. If it's to center-set section-level headers, don't encase `\section` and/or `\section*` directives in `center` directives. Instead, just execute the following instructions in the preamble

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
```

and then run `\section` and `\section*` in the body of the document without placing them in `center` environments.

The framelines in the following screenshot are there because I've loaded the geometry package with the option `showframe`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} % 13pt is not a valid option
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chào buổi sáng mọi người}
\end{document}
```